# How to configure Selenium so it would run everytime project is built on TFS, machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, tfsbuild

Sorry if the topic should be more specific but I am still a newbie here.

So that is the problem:

in a project I am working in i got Selenium tests. And now it is configured in that way so everytime I commit some changes - solution is beeing built on a virtual machine. When it comes to Selenium tests I`ve got an error like:

*No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:46005...*

So the question is:

Why do I got this error?
How should I properly configure the build TFS and Selenium tests that it would work.

- I`ve checked the Selenium Server (it is working)
- tried to change driver from IE to Chrome (not working)

Thanks you in advance. I am dealing with this for days.

Greetings

Comment: Can you ping the ip? maybe the port is blocked?

Comment: I don`t know if its blocked it is not avaible by "netstat -na" either.

Comment: So you can either open the port and add a exception in the firewall or change the project config to use a different port

Comment: Ive checked and it looks like Selenium uses different port for an every instance of IE which is opened with a new tests (like 46263, 46200 45964, etc.). 
So if I got 40 tests Ive got 40 different ports. Doesnt looks like a good idea to open every of them.

Comment: Maybe open the port for a short [time frame](http://superuser.com/questions/842698/how-to-open-a-firewall-port-in-windows-using-power-shell)